# Change the reference of a struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, reference

I have a while that performs some calculation and I have to iterate in some nodes.

My structs are:

```
typedef struct {
    int pointer; 
    int *n; //an array
} ENTRY;

typedef struct {
    int nofentries; //number of entries
    RENTRY *entries; //array of entries
} NODE;
```

My function is:

```
NODE *choose_node(NODE *currentnode, ENTRY *input) {
    NODE *n;
    //it copies a node by using memcpy (including its struct fields)...
    n = node_clone(currentnode);
    while(true) {
        //my computation to choose a entry....
        if(my computation is true)
           return n;

        //my doubt is here:

        //I have a stack that stores the visited elements
        //the push function does NOT copy the NODE
        //it aims only to store the references
        stack_push(stack, n);
        //then we update the node for the next level
        //this function gets other node (it returns a pointer of a new NODE)
        n = get_node(n->entries[entry]->pointer);
    }
}
```

Is my stack able to store correctly the node references if I change where *n* is pointing? My afraid is to lost the reference of visited nodes.

Then, if I pop the nodes from my stack, will the result be expected?

Which problems I will have here?

Comment: I think you can put your code more appropriately, Then it will make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack should keep your reference to the old pointer, so slapping a new pointer over n's reference to it won't lose the reference on the stack. Seems like it will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you. I was checking it, but I was not sure. =)